# How to get one or two of data value in Controller Codeigniter when using AJAX Post

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, codeigniter

can someone help me with my code, i have AJAX json type POST and i wanto to get one or two of data send to controller in codeigniter, i wanto to add conditional function where the data from json.

My JSON

```
$('#add_people').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    var id_people = $('#id_people').val();
    var name_people = $('#name_people').val();
    var phone_people = $('#phone_people').val();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url  : "<?php echo base_url('add_people_data')?>",
        dataType : "JSON",
        data : {id_people:id_people , name_people:name_people, phone_people:phone_people},
        success: function(data){
            $("#show_people").html('<img src="assets/img/user/spinner.gif"> <h4>Loading data...</h4>');
            $('#modal-add_people').modal('hide');
            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
            $('[name="id_people"]').val("");
            $('[name="name_people"]').val("");
            $('[name="phone_people"]').val("");
            var loadUrl = "<?php echo base_url('show-people-data')?>";
            $("#show_people").load(loadUrl);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

My Controler

```
public function add_people_data()
        {
    $id_people = $this->input->post('id_people');
    $name_people = $this->input->post('name_people');
    $phone_people = $this->input->post('phone_people');
    
    $cekassignreviewer=$this->Model_reviewer->checkassignreviewer('data_people', $id_people, $name_people, $phone_people);
    
    if ($cekassignreviewer > 0) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('failed',
        "<script>swal({
            title:'Failed!',
            text: 'Number of people has been added',
            icon: 'error',
            confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success'
        });
        </script>");
        redirect(base_url('setting-reviewer'));
    }else{
        $data=$this->Model_reviewer->add_people();
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

My Model

```
function add_people()
{
    $data = array(
            'id_people'    => $this->input->post('uniid_reviewer'), 
            'name_people'   => $this->input->post('name_people'), 
            'phone_people'   => $this->input->post('phone_people'), 
        );
    $result=$this->db->insert('data_people',$data);
    return $result;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean you are unable to send post data to your controller?

Comment: i can send my data to controller, but when i add
$id_people = $this->input->post('id_people');
$name_people = $this->input->post('name_people');
$phone_people = $this->input->post('phone_people');

its not add the variabel into $this->Model_reviewer->checkassignreviewer('data_people', $id_people, $name_people, $phone_people);

Comment: can you debug `$_POST` before sending it to the model?

Answer (score 0):

**IncomingRequest Class For CodeIgniter 4**

If you are not within a controller, but still need access to the application’s Request object, you can get a copy of it through the Services class:

```
$request = \Config\Services::request();
```

With CodeIgniter’s built in methods you can simply do this:

```
$something = $request->getVar('foo');
```

The `getVar()` method will pull from `$_REQUEST`, so will return any data from `$_GET`, `$_POST`, or `$_COOKIE`. While this is convenient, you will often need to use a more specific method, like:

```
$request->getGet()
$request->getPost()
$request->getServer()
$request->getCookie()
```

In addition, there are a few utility methods for retrieving information from either `$_GET` or `$_POST`, while maintaining the ability to control the order you look for it:

```
$request->getPostGet() - checks $_POST first, then $_GET
$request->getGetPost() - checks $_GET first, then $_POST
```